# How to change my apps Tile Graphic

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I feel terrible having to ask but everything I have come across is for end users looking to pin installed app tiles to the start menu.

When you create an app in VS you are given a graphic that is used in the menu but when you pin the app to your start menu you get a blank tile in the chosen accent color with the name of your application on it.

I would like to know how to add a graphic to this tile if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change the Background.png image in your project and rebuild. There are separate images for splash screen, icon and tile.

Comment: ... and remember to set it to content

Answer (score 1):

The image 'Background.png' is included in the default project and this is used for this image. This can be changed in the properties of the project. It is the 'Background image' under 'Tile Options' on the Application tab.

Please note that, as per the App Submission requirements, this image must be 173 x 173 pixels in size and be in PNG format.

This image casn also be remotely updated by sending a [Tile format Push Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545%28VS.92%29.aspx) message or by setting a [TileSchedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769548%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: Cool! Didn't know about a TileSchedule yet so far.

Answer (score 1):

It's the Background.png image by default. It should be 173x173 PNG image. Also, if you want the theme color background (like with built-in apps), be sure to make the background color of the tile image `Color.Transparent`.

If you're asking about a dynamic start screen tile, you'll need to check into the push notification system, as this is the only way to change the tile image based on external influence (=when your app is not currently running).